# Encoding text stream from PDF to UCS-2 in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pdf

I'm using `CGPDFStringGetBytePtr` to get a `const char *` called `str` from a `CGPDFStringRef` popped from a PDF stream. I want to convert `str` to `UCS-2` representation (an expression like `...\303...`) using `iconv`, but I don't know how `str` was encoded. How I decide this? Or, what was the likely encoding (given that I'm streaming a PDF on a Mac)? I may be missing the wood for the trees.

***** EDIT #1.

```
CFStringRef aStringRef = CGPDFStringCopyTextString(aCGStringRef);
NSString * aString = (NSString *) aStringRef;

const char * bytes = [aString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
bytes = [SKTextEncoding convertText:bytes
                         toEncoding:"UCS-2"
                       fromEncoding:"UTF-8"];

NSLog(@"%s", bytes);
```

***** EDIT #2. String and bytes before any conversion, i.e. result of:

```
              CGPDFStringRef aCGStringRef = NULL;
              CGPDFObjectGetValue(anObjectRef,
                                  kCGPDFObjectTypeString,
                                  &aCGStringRef);
              CFStringRef aStringRef =         
                    CGPDFStringCopyTextString(aCGStringRef);
              NSString * aString = (NSString *) aStringRef;
              const char * bytes = [aString   
                    cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
              NSLog(@"string: %@____bytes: %s", aString, bytes);
```

2011-05-25 16:08:00.966 Test[1813:207] string:  Æ____bytes:  √Ü

2011-05-25 16:08:00.967 Test[1813:207] string:  Ï____bytes:  √è

2011-05-25 16:08:00.967 Test[1813:207] string:  ®*_*_bytes:  ¬Æ

2011-05-25 16:08:00.968 Test[1813:207] string:  ﬂ____bytes:  Ô¨Ç

2011-05-25 16:08:00.968 Test[1813:207] string:  ³*_*_bytes:  ¬≥

2011-05-25 16:08:00.969 Test[1813:207] string:  ã____bytes:  √£

2011-05-25 16:08:00.969 Test[1813:207] string:  ï____bytes:  √Ø

2011-05-25 16:08:00.970 Test[1813:207] string:  ³*_*_bytes:  ¬≥

2011-05-25 16:08:00.970 Test[1813:207] string:  µ____bytes:  ¬µ

2011-05-25 16:08:00.971 Test[1813:207] string:  Â____bytes:  √Ç

2011-05-25 16:08:00.971 Test[1813:207] string:  Ü____bytes:  √ú

Comment: Yes. I probably added the code to my second edit after your comment arrived.

Comment: It looks like your strings aren’t correct. Does `CGPDFObjectGetValue()` return a true value?

Comment: Yes - it returns `1` every time. In what way are they not correct? Should they be identical?

Comment: I’m at loss here. As far as I can tell, your code should work.

Comment: This may be a very stupid question, but I'll clutch at straws anyway - am I in any way applying the `UTF-8` encoding twice? i.e. encoding once, and then encoding again, i.e. a composite map, in the above? If I am, would that scramble the bytes?

Comment: You’re not. `CGPDFStringRef` is an opaque type representing a string in a certain encoding that’s not public and unknown to you. `CGPDFStringCopyTextString()` creates a `CFString/NSString` object and chooses an encoding for it. When you send it `-cStringUsingEncoding:`, it returns a C string with the encoding you’ve specified, potentially converting its internal representation to UTF-8 if needed.

Comment: Ok. So my strings are correct because the bytes and the string, when NSLogged, should be identical?

Comment: Well, `%s` doesn’t understand UTF-8. You can inspect the numeric representation of `bytes` to see if they match the corresponding string, and I don’t see why they shouldn’t.

Comment: Right, but I'm not sure I understand again. How do you extract the numeric representation of a string of bytes (such as to `\300\215` etc. or do you mean casting individual bytes as integers)? If it's the former, i.e. to something like `\300\215`, that is possibly what I'm after.

Comment: (I'm essentially at a complete loss now. I have so many things in place -- eg. CMap parser working etc. -- and I can't hook it up. I really appreciate your efforts.)

Comment: `const char *` is a pointer to a sequence of `chars`, so you can iterate over them and print them as `%d` (which is similar to casting them as integers).

Comment: OK - that's what I thought you meant and the results show they match sometimes but not nearly always.

Comment: There are two reasons I can think of for them not to match: lossy encoding and Unicode normalisation. I don’t think it should be possible to have lossy encoding when the target encoding is UTF-8 but, since we’re running out of ideas here, try sending the string `-canBeConvertedToEncoding:` to see if it can be converted to UTF-8. As for Unicode normalisation, try using the `-decomposed…` or `-precomposed…` methods.

Comment: `aString` in Edit#2 can always be converted to `UTF-8` (querying with `[aString canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` always returns `YES` i.e. `1`). Also, are you referring to the `NSString` instance method `decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`? It always gives the same result as encoding with `UTF-8`.

Comment: Is there any chance the bytes have been encrypted with `zlib` and are yet to be unencrypted? (I thought `CGPDFScanner` took care of unencrypting things, so the bytes I'm seeing should be unencrypted no?)

Comment: If the PDF is encrypted, you need to unlock it via `CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword()`. Does zlib do encryption?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean encryption, I meant compression/decompression. My bad. The PDF is unlocked (I also have a `CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword()` call if needed, on this occasion it's not). Still... there's no compression on the bytes at this stage right?

Comment: I mean, the text that's popping from `CGPDFScannerRef` is just a sequence of character identifiers (CIDs). I want to apply the Adobe-Japan1-UCS2 CMap to this, but I don't want some encoding messing up the CIDs on the way. That seems to be happening (eg. when I take some characters from the/any text and apply the CMap I get weird results - I'm pretty certain that the CMap code is all correct).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `CGPDFStringGetBytePtr()`, use `CGPDFStringCopyTextString()`. The latter function returns a `CFString` object (owned by the caller) that, because of toll-free bridging, can be used as an `NSString` object.

Being an `NSString` object, you can send it `-cStringUsingEncoding:` to get a `const char *` pointer with the string representation in a given encoding, or `-getCString:maxLength:encoding:` to store the string representation in a given encoding. For instance, you could get a C string in UTF-8 encoding and then use libiconv to convert it to UCS-2:

```
CFPDFStringRef pdfString = …;
NSString *str = (NSString *)CGPDFStringCopyTextString(pdfString);
const char *bytes = [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// use libiconv to convert the string in 'bytes' from UTF-8 to UCS-2
[str release];
```

Alternatively, you could use the Core Foundation functions for strings. I personally prefer to use their Foundation counterpart classes, though.

Comment: @Bavarious: Thanks for your post. I started out using `CGPDFCopyTextString()` and then onto `NSString` but I seemed to be losing bytes. Some of the PDF text is in Japanese, and I'm going to apply the Adobe-Japan1-UCS2 CMap.

Comment: @SK9 Can you edit your question and paste the code you’ve used?

Comment: @SK9 Your code looks correct except for not releasing `aString`. If you `NSLog()` both `aString` and `bytes` before the conversion to UCS-2, do you also see that some bytes have been lost?

Comment: @Bavarious: I'm releasing further on (I doubt it's related). One second.

Comment: @Bavarious: I've posted a second edit to my question with some code and the results (string verses bytes).